# JavaScript - Comments duplicating on another div

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a comment box and I managed to append whatever I type to a div I wanted, however I have added another input and trying to append that along with the comments, however when I do this the second time,it appends both the previous and current comment therefore the previous comment duplicates. I know I'm doing something wrong in my display_commnents function, however I'm not entirely sure what it could be, basically I just want whatever is entered on both title and comments to append on the comment-box with title on top and comment just below. Below is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Write New Post</h1>
    <form>
        <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Title" value="">
        <textarea id="" placeholder="Leave us a comment" value=""></textarea>
        <input id="giphy" type="text">
        <div class="btn">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="comment">
            <button id="clear">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="comments">
    <h2>Comments</h2>
    <div id="comment-box" value="submit">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my JS code:

```
    const title = document.querySelector('#title')
const field = document.querySelector('textarea');
const textBackUp = title.getAttribute('placeholder')
const backUp = field.getAttribute('placeholder')
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const clear = document.getElementById('clear')
const submit = document.querySelector('#submit')
// const comments = document.querySelector('#comment-box')
const titleText = document.getElementById('title')
const comments = document.getElementById('comment-box')

let title_arr = [];
let comments_arr = [];

title.onfocus = function(){
    this.setAttribute('placeholder', '')
}

title.onblur = function(){
    this.setAttribute('placeholder', textBackUp)
}

field.onfocus = function(){
    this.setAttribute('placeholder','')
    this.style.borderColor = '#333'
    btn.style.display = 'block'
} // when clicking on this, placeholder changes into ' ', border colour changes and buttons will appear.

field.onblur = function(){
    this.setAttribute('placeholder',backUp)
} //click away, placeholder returns

const display_comments = () => {
    let list = '<ul>'
    title_arr.forEach(title => {
    comments_arr.forEach(comment => {
        list += `<li>${title} <br>${comment}`
    })
    })
    list += '</ul>'
    comments.innerHTML = list
}

clear.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    btn.style.display = 'none'
    title.value = ''
    field.value = ''
    display_comments()
}

submit.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const head = title.value;
    const content = field.value;
    if(head.length > 0){
        title_arr.push(head)
        display_comments();
        title.value = '';
    }
    if(content.length > 0){
        comments_arr.push(content)
        display_comments();
        field.value = '';
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: display_comments is being called after every array push and you re-iterate the complete array again and again, so as the array grows it iterate each element

Comment: What do you want to happen if user fills in a title three times and submits all three, and then types one comment and submits it. What is the desired output? Should each title be accompanied by an empty comment? Should the last comment be accompanied by an empty title? How will the output distinguish between titles and comments?

Comment: @trincot Basically I just want whatever is entered to be displayed without the previous comments being pushed as well. I successfully managed to do this with the comments only but now I've added the title box in, the comments just duplicates + adding the new comment in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a double nested loop, producing a Cartesion product of the all the introduced titles and the comments.

To solve this, use only one array for collecting the input, so that title and comment are always kept together in one array entry. Such an entry can be an object with two properties, one for the title, and one for the comment.

Here is your code adapted, just for fixing that issue:

```js
const title = document.querySelector('#title')
const field = document.querySelector('textarea');
const textBackUp = title.getAttribute('placeholder')
const backUp = field.getAttribute('placeholder')
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const clear = document.getElementById('clear')
const submit = document.querySelector('#submit')
// const comments = document.querySelector('#comment-box')
const titleText = document.getElementById('title')
const comments = document.getElementById('comment-box')

let arr = []; // Only one array

title.onfocus = function(){
    this.setAttribute('placeholder', '');
}

title.onblur = function(){
    this.setAttribute('placeholder', textBackUp);
}

field.onfocus = function(){
    this.setAttribute('placeholder','');
    this.style.borderColor = '#333';
    btn.style.display = 'block';
}

field.onblur = function(){
    this.setAttribute('placeholder', backUp);
}

const display_comments = () => {
    let list = '<ul>';
    // Only one loop -- over objects with two properties
    arr.forEach(({head, content}) => {
        list += `<li><b>${head}</b><br>${content}`;
    })
    list += '</ul>';
    comments.innerHTML = list;
}

clear.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    btn.style.display = 'none';
    title.value = '';
    field.value = '';
    display_comments();
}

submit.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const head = title.value;
    const content = field.value;
    // Only one if-block
    if(head.length > 0 || content.length > 0){
        arr.push({head, content}); // Only one push -- of an object 
        display_comments();
        title.value = '';
        field.value = '';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Write New Post</h1>
    <form>
        <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Title" value="">
        <textarea id="" placeholder="Leave us a comment" value=""></textarea>
        <div class="btn">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="comment">
            <button id="clear">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="comments">
    <h2>Comments</h2>
    <div id="comment-box" value="submit">
    </div>
</div>
```